# Can future processes free themselves?

Tags: r, future

i have a script/workframe that calls a function with the future package. The function does not return anything, but instead starts an API-Call, something like this:

```
library(future)
future::plan("multisession")
future_get_function = function (msg) {
  link <- ("http://127.0.0.1:7774/echo?")
  message <- list(msg=msg)     
  httr::GET(link, query=message)
  Sys.sleep(20)
}

future::future({
   future_get_function(msg)
}, globals = list(msg=msg)}
```

```
library(plumber)

#* Echo back the input
#* @param msg The message to echo
#* @get /echo
function(msg="") {
  print("received something")
  list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
}
```

Now, from what ive seen, I need to free up the processes that are done with the `value` function afterwards, correct? Otherwise, if I have more calls then processers/tasks available, they are stuck?

So is there a function that i can insert at the end of `future_get_function` or somewhere in the `future` call (promises would also be fine), that frees the process automatically once its done, without me having to call `value` or similar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Future processes definitely free themselves after completion.
You could use `then` to follow up promises completion, and `promise_all` to check when all promises are finished :

```
library(future)
library(promises)
plan(multisession)

tic <- Sys.time()

future_get_function = function (msg,wait) {
  #link <- ("http://127.0.0.1:7774/echo?")
  #message <- list(msg=msg)     
  #httr::GET(link, query=message)
  print(paste(msg,": launched after",round(difftime(Sys.time(),tic),1), 'seconds'))
  Sys.sleep(wait)
  invisible(msg)
}

f1 <- future(future_get_function('msg1',5))
f2 <- future(future_get_function('msg2',10))

f_after <- function(res) {
  print(paste(res,"sent after",round(difftime(Sys.time(),tic),1), 'seconds'))}

f_failed <- function(res) {
  print(paste("future failed"))}

f_end <- function(res) {
  print(paste("All messages sent after",round(difftime(Sys.time(),tic),1), 'seconds'))}


promises::then(f1, onFulfilled = f_after, onRejected = f_failed)
promises::then(f2, onFulfilled = f_after, onRejected = f_failed)

f_wait_all <- promises::promise_all(f1,f2)
promises::then(f_wait_all, onFulfilled = f_end, onRejected = f_failed)

[1] "msg1 : launched after 0 seconds"
[1] "msg1 sent after 5.1 seconds"
[1] "msg2 : launched after 0.2 seconds"
[1] "msg2 sent after 10.2 seconds"
[1] "All messages sent after 10.2 seconds"
```